# how does an app detect device on network

Tags: linux

I use apps that interact with their specific devices. An example is Roku. The device is Roku and I use their Android App. Another is my Denon Audio receiver and it too has an app to control it. I'm looking to write app/hardware service. how does an app detect device on network and vice-versa?

Comment: I've seen Roku my apps scan the subnet, and I assume they are doing something like issuing an HTTP GET against port 80 and looking for a particular known response.

Comment: I have never watched wireshark or tailed my router log while it scanned though, to know just what takes place.

Comment: Could also be [a broadcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address), though the Roku app I've used definitely stepped through the subnet incrementally...

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I don't know what Roku is but what you are describing sounds like [service discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_discovery) as part of zeroconf.

One relatively known example is [DNS-SD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking#Service_discovery). You can think of it as sending periodically multicast UDP messages containing stuff such as "*I am at address X and I provide service Y*" to some well-known address. Whoever is interested will pick up the information associated.

Comment: Some services, most prominently local game servers, also use UDP broadcasting. Here, the client sends a broadcast packet asking for server information. Then all servers that receive it reply.